# Stored procedure execution plan WITH RECOMPILE

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a stored procedure that runs every 5 minutes in a job on SQL server.  The job will run for 80% of the time with no results , this is expected, but when it does have data to process it is a very long process.
The code is like this below simplified.

```
IF exists (Select top 1 col1 from tbl1 where processed = '0' )
BEGIN
    HUGE PROCESS with multiple selects joins and updates
END
```

How will the execution plan evaluate this SP?  Is this a rare case that using with WITH RECOMPILE is the best option?

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: Better understanding of execution plans - how using an if statement in a stored procedure when it determines such a large discrepancy will be processed. Using WITH RECOMPILE or OPTION (RECOMPILE) can produce better execution plans in limiting situations and if it does what are the parameters of those situations.

Comment: Thats too broad for a single question. I would suggest doing some reading about all that, and analysing your execution plans and then asking specific questions when things come up that you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Include Actual Execution Plan` option in the SQL Server Management Studio, you will see that when the `IF` expression is evaluated to `false` its body's operators are not included in the execution plan.

So, there is no need to worry - the SQL Engine will use correct execution plan and will not touch the data.

The [recompile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/recompile-a-stored-procedure?view=sql-server-ver15) option can be helpful in particular queries but I believe you can skip it for now.